# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '....' (65)

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-2003, pantheon

This is the first time I am setting up a remote connection and I am doing this.

```
mysql -u user -password -h dbserver.dev.5bfed886-8150-4a8d-b0d5-4c7cffb5c54c.drush.in -P 11831 dbname
```

I get this error back.

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'dbserver.$ENV.$SITE.drush.in' (65)
```

I have scoured the web I am not able to find a solution, I would appreciate any help. I apologize beforehand if any information is missing (I am a first timer).

Comment: Please provide a code snippet where this connection is being used.

Comment: Also, please provide the code that is creating the connection

Comment: do echo $ENV and echo $SITE, do u get meaningful values? Also, put the actual IP address -hxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx not variables. Also... it might be your remote server is not configured to accept remote clients.

Comment: @AaronFranco this is command line syntax, there is no "code" involved in this.

Comment: Okay,  try typing the URL of the host, and not using that variable "dbserver"

Comment: and just to make sure, this is something u type in the command line and not use embedded in some code, right?

Comment: @AaronFranco, I type this in the command line, there is not other code. I have also updated the question to provide more information (I had to get permission)

Comment: I see,  best remove any sensitive info!

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka doing an echo, doesn't give me anything meaningful. Doing and echo $ENV or echo $SITE just returns $ENV or $SITE respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysql -uuser -p -hdbserver.dev.5bfed886-8150-4a8d-b0d5-4c7cffb5c54c.drush.in -P11831
```

mysql ask you for password after running

Comment: That worked! Thank you! (ofcourse I have to choose the database for it use later)

Comment: You are welcome, Please check answered your question

Comment: Why  is this happening though? And what is error (65). Do you know of a reference list for these errors?

Comment: Are you still having errors? your error is not "65", your error is 2003: Error: 2003 (CR_CONN_HOST_ERROR)

Message: Can't connect to MySQL server on '%s' (%d)

Comment: No, I am not having errors anymore. I was just curious. I want to know what the (65) is.

Answer (score 1):

As the last commenter mentioned, you need to "wake" up the site. However, this can be accomplished just by reloading the homepage.

https://pantheon.io/docs/debug-connections/

> Services such as MySQL and SFTP are running; however, the local client
>   is unable to connect due to an idled container or DNS issues. Before
>   further troubleshooting, wake the environment by loading the home page...

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to connect to Pantheon (which it looks like you are), you might just need to wake up your instance. I did that with `terminus drush --site=[site_name] --env=[environment_name] st` where [site_name] is replaced with the machine name of your site and [environment_name] is replaced with the machine name of the environment you wish to awaken.